# Trouble Loading local symbols in WinDBG - Kernel Driver

Tags: windbg, debug-symbols, windows-kernel

I cannot figure out why my local symbols are not loading for a kernel driver compiled using WDK and VS2013.
I build the driver and place myDriver.pdb in C:\Symbols\local, and copy the myDriver.sys to my virtual machine.  Using VirtualKD I start the debugger, install the driver, and look at my loaded modules or try to set a breakpoint on myDriver!DriverEntry.  When I try the breakpoint I get:

```
BP expression myDriver.sys!DriverEntry could not be resolved, adding deferred bp
```

My symbol path is:

```
C:\Symbols\local;srv*C:\Symbols\symcache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

When I try to .reload /f myDriver.sys I get:

```
kd> .reload /f myDriver.sys

"myDriver.sys" was not found in the image list.
Debugger will attempt to load "myDriver.sys" at given base 00000000`00000000.

Please provide the full image name, including the extension (i.e. kernel32.dll)
for more reliable results.Base address and size overrides can be given as
.reload <image.ext>=<base>,<size>.
DBGENG:  myDriver.sys - Partial symbol image load missing image info
DBGHELP: No header for myDriver.sys.  Searching for dbg file
DBGHELP: c:\symbols\local\myDriver.dbg - file not found
DBGHELP: c:\symbols\local\sys\myDriver.dbg - path not found
DBGHELP: c:\symbols\local\symbols\sys\myDriver.dbg - path not found
DBGHELP: .\myDriver.dbg - file not found
DBGHELP: .\sys\myDriver.dbg - path not found
DBGHELP: .\symbols\sys\myDriver.dbg - path not found
DBGHELP: myDriver.sys missing debug info.  Searching for pdb anyway

DBGHELP: myDriver - private symbols & lines 
    c:\symbols\local\myDriver.pdb - unmatched
Unable to add module at 00000000`00000000
```

Any ideas as to how I can fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because driver isn`t loaded yet. Deffered bp is OK. They will be resolved on driver load. This is normal behavior, no need to "fix this".

Comment: I have already installed the driver so shouldn't it already be loaded?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, ended up being an issue loading the driver and it never actually got to my driver's code to load the symbol.